# Simplify MS SQL Statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read a great post on JOINS, [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) but I don't think it helps my issue.

I would like to combine two select statements into a single select statement AND, make it efficient for any databases to query.

Here is what I have

```
SELECT
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT,dbo.SEM_AGENT,dbo.PATTERN
                        WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
                        AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
                        AND Name like '%Staten Island%'
                        AND dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '11.%'
                        AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE 'Windows%') AS 'Windows-SEP-11',
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT,dbo.SEM_AGENT,dbo.PATTERN
                        WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
                        AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
                        AND Name like '%Staten Island%'
                        AND dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '12.%'
                        AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE 'Windows%') AS 'Windows-SEP-12',
(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                        FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT,dbo.SEM_AGENT,dbo.PATTERN
                        WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
                        AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
                        AND Name like '%Staten Island%'
                        AND dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '11.%'
                        AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE 'Mac%') AS 'Mac-SEP-11',
(SELECT COUNT(*)
                        FROM dbo.sem_computer, [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER], dbo.IDENTITY_MAP, dbo.SEM_CLIENT,dbo.SEM_AGENT,dbo.PATTERN
                        WHERE [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
                        AND dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
                        AND dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
                        AND Name like '%Staten Island%'
                        AND dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '12.%'
                        AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE 'Mac%')  AS 'Mac-SEP-12'
```

How to shrink this SQL statement? Even if I use Inner Joins (which I'm working on), this statement is quite processor intensive (not to mention it seems really inefficient)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this using `Conditional Aggregate`.

Also use proper `INNER JOIN` syntax to Join two tables instead of old style comma separated join. Keep the filters in `Where` clause

```
SELECT Count(CASE
               WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '11.%'
                    AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE 'Windows%' THEN 1
             END) AS 'Windows-SEP-11',
       Count(CASE
               WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '12.%'
                    AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE 'Windows%' THEN 1
             END) AS 'Windows-SEP-12',
       Count(CASE
               WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '11.%'
                    AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE 'Mac%' THEN 1
             END) AS 'Mac-SEP-11',
       Count(CASE
               WHEN dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE '12.%'
                    AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE 'Mac%' THEN 1
             END) AS 'Mac-SEP-12'
FROM   dbo.sem_computer
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
               ON [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.SEM_AGENT
               ON SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.SEM_CLIENT
               ON dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.IDENTITY_MAP
               ON dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.PATTERN
               ON dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
WHERE  Name LIKE '%Staten Island%'
```

Comment: What does `THEN 1` mean? Does the `1` mean TRUE?

Comment: @SohniMahiwal - Its just a value to count you can keep anything.

Answer (score 2):

Building upon the providing answer, I think a more elegant solution is to hold filtering values in a separate table (separate logic from data).

However, this will work only if the conditions are disjoint (a pair of values will hit a maximum of one condition), otherwise multiple "hits" will count for more options.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AgentAndOsFilter
(
   Id INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
   AgentVersion VARCHAR(8),
   Os VARCHAR(16)
)
```

This can be populated with your filtering pairs:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.AgentAndOsFilter (AgentVersion, Os)
VALUES ('11.%', 'Windows%'), ('12.%', 'Windows%'), ('11.%', 'Mac%'), ('12.%', 'Mac%')
```

The query can look like this:

```
SELECT F.Id, Count(1) Cnt
FROM   dbo.sem_computer
       INNER JOIN [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER]
               ON [dbo].[V_SEM_COMPUTER].COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.SEM_AGENT
               ON SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID = dbo.SEM_AGENT.COMPUTER_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.SEM_CLIENT
               ON dbo.SEM_CLIENT.COMPUTER_ID = SEM_COMPUTER.COMPUTER_ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.IDENTITY_MAP
               ON dbo.SEM_CLIENT.GROUP_ID = IDENTITY_MAP.ID
       INNER JOIN dbo.PATTERN
               ON dbo.PATTERN.PATTERN_IDX = dbo.SEM_AGENT.PATTERN_IDX
       INNER JOIN dbo.AgentAndOsFilter F 
               ON dbo.SEM_AGENT.AGENT_VERSION LIKE F.AgentVersion 
                   AND dbo.SEM_COMPUTER.OPERATION_SYSTEM LIKE F.Os
WHERE  Name LIKE '%Staten Island%' 
GROUP BY F.Id
```

Another advantage of this solution is changes in the configuration (new versions of agents, new operating systems) simply means changing some records in a table.